# Timers.Timer paralyze script

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to run [this](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/creating-a-timer-event-in-powershell/) example:

```
Clear-Host
$timer = [Timers.Timer]::new()
$timer.Interval = 200
$action = {
    if($complete -eq 8){
        write-host "completed $complete" -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host "Timer stopped" -ForegroundColor Red
        $timer.stop()
        Unregister-Event thetimer
    }
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed `
–SourceIdentifier  thetimer -Action $action

$complete = 0
$timer.Start()

while($true){
    Write-Host "Script working: $complete" -ForegroundColor Green
    Start-Sleep -m 400
    $complete++
}
```

But when timer stops, the script is paralyzed.

What i'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your code fundamentally won't work as intended unless you execute it directly in the *global* scope (by pasting it at the prompt or by *dot-sourcing* a script that contains it).

  - The reason is that **a script block passed to [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent)'s `-Action` parameter runs inside a *dynamic module*, which sees only the *global* scope's variables, not that of any other caller**, such as a script's.
- If you do run from the global scope, the **hang is caused by calling [`Unregister-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unregister-event) *inside the `-Action` script block***:

  - **Call it from the *caller's scope* instead** (i.e. from the same scope where `Register-ObjectEvent` was called).
  - That the code *hangs* when called from inside the `-Action` script block (happens up to at least PowerShell 7.1, the version current as of this writing) should be considered a *bug*; it seems to occur when *more events are pending* at the time `Unregister-Event` is called; the problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #16154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16154)

The following is a self-contained, working sample that you can also invoke from a script:

```bash
$timer = [Timers.Timer]::new()
$timer.Interval = 200

$action = {
  # Note: This script block generally does NOT see the caller's variables.
  # Refer to the originating timer object with $Event.Sender or $args[0]
  $timer = $Event.Sender
  # Get the variable object passed to -MessageData, via $Event.MessageData
  $counter = $Event.MessageData.Value
  # Note: Since you're only *getting* an *integer* value, you needn't worry
  #       about thread synchronization.
  if ($timer.Enabled -and $counter -ge 8) { 
      write-host "completed $counter" -ForegroundColor Red
      write-host "Timer stopped" -ForegroundColor Red
      $timer.stop()
      # Do NOT try to call Unregister-Event here - it'll cause a hang.
  }
}

# Initialize the counter variable.
$complete = 0

# Get the variable as a variable *object* that can be passed to the -Action
# script block with -MessageData.
$counterVarObject = Get-Variable complete

# Register the event and pass the variable object with -MessageData.
$evtJob = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed `
                               –SourceIdentifier thetimer `
                               -Action $action -MessageData $counterVarObject

$timer.Start()

try {
  while ($timer.Enabled) { # Loop until the timer stops.
      Write-Host "Script working: $complete" -ForegroundColor Green
      Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 400
      $complete++
  }
}
finally { # This is called even if the loop is aborted with Ctrl-C.
  # Remove the event job, which also unregisters the event.
  $evtJob | Remove-Job -Force
}
```